# Django Dynamic Setting : access DEBUG from admin page

Tags: python, django, debugging, signals, settings

I Use django 3.2
I need to change DEBUG option from admin page
to do that I install Django-constance

I add these in setting.py:

```
from constance import config

CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
    'DEBUG':(True,'Debug mode'),
}
    # answer_the_question()
DEBUG=config.DEBUG
```

and this signal in models.py

```
@receiver(config_updated)
def constance_updated(sender, key, old_value, new_value, **kwargs):
    print(sender, 'DEBUG', old_value, new_value)
```

but its not work

Answer (score 0):

Did you add:
'constance'
in INSTALLED_APPS at settings.py?

you also needs to ou a new value like

```
 CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
    'DEBUG':(True, False)
}
```

Try that!
or if you wanna describe with a string you need a use a tuple:

```
 CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
    'DEBUG':((True, 'DEBUG MODE'), (False,'UNDEBUG MODE'))
}
```